# can't use jquery request variable twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to use a date submitted through jquery datepicker more than once.

```
 //date picker 
$(function() {
    var date = $('#datepickerstart').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',  minDate:0 }).val();
});

$(function() {
    var date =  $( "#datepickerend" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',  minDate:0 }).val();
});

// first use
var startdate = { request : $('#startdate').val() };
var enddate = { request : $('#startdate').val() };               

$('#myForm').ajaxForm( {
    url: eventurl,
    data: { 
        stdate: startdate,
        edate: enddate
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $("#mydiv").html(response);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#mydiv").html(errorThrown);
    }
});

});
```

This works once, if I then try and use it again get null.  If I try use it hear like this

```
$.ajax({   
    url: othercontroller,
    data: { 
        start: startdate,
        end: enddate,
        useraction: otherstuff
    },
    type:"POST"
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that includes these two lines and all the lines in between? There's not enough to go off here. This should work with zero problems. Something else is affecting the value...

Comment: Also, if this is caused by a syntax error, which isn't all that unlikely, your console would've produced an error.

Comment: @War10ck added code , hard variables in place of 2nd AJAX request work, so code is working but startdate not getting passed in

Comment: This is a lot more helpful. Thank you for posting. A couple of questions came to mind after reviewing your edit. 1. Are you meaning to store `#startdate`'s value in `enddate`? As it's currently written, you're going to send the same value to the backend for both variables. 2. Where is `#startdate` defined? I see two datepickers `#datepickerstart` and `#datepickerend` but I never see `#startdate`. 3. By your use of `.val()` I assume you're applying the datepicker to a text input (i.e. perhaps `#datepickerstart` and `#datepickerend` are text inputs). Is this correct?

Comment: Ran out of space for #3. If my assumption in #3 is correct in my previous comment, I'd suggest using the official [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) method (i.e. `$('#datepickerstart').datepicker('getDate')`) to get the value as oppose to `.val()`. While `.val()` may work, it's not clear what _"magic"_, if you will, jQuery is doing in the background. Best to be safe and use the supported method instead.

Comment: @War10ck correct #startdate is the name of text field, #datepickerstart are the id of the form field.    I tried $('#datepickerstart').datepicker('getDate') it only works for the first method.  Also it messes up my spinner ;) for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @War10ck suggestion I was able to use $('#datepickerstart').datepicker('getDate') for the 2nd use of the date, after using .val() for the 1st use.

Answer (score -3):

as you haven't posted the datepicker i assume that some event destroys the dom-object. anyway just do:

```js
var startdatesecond = startdate;
```

Comment: I did try that to no avail